# Very Weird PHP is overwriting variable assignment with 1

Tags: php, arrays, variable-assignment

Anybody got a clue what's going on here?

Let's take this very simple piece of code:

```
$p_id = array();
foreach($opp->participants as $party) {
    echo "ID value from data:" . var_dump($party->id) . "<br>";

    echo "Base array:" .  var_dump($p_id) . "<br>";
    $p_uuid = array();
    $p_assignment_id = array();
    $p_id = array_push($p_id, "$party->id");
    echo "Dump array result:" .var_dump($p_id) . "<br>";
}
```

This is the output I'm getting from this (Yes, that's the formatting of the output too):

```
int(295) ID value from data:<br>
array(0) { } Base array:<br>
int(1) Dump array result:<br>
int(298) ID value from data:<br>
array(0) { } Base array:<br>
int(1) Dump array result:<br>
int(301) ID value from data:<br>
array(0) { } Base array:<br>
int(1) Dump array result:<br>
```

This is obviously a noob question, but I honestly have no idea why the output looks like this.

if I use `print_r`, this is the result I get:

```
295 ID value from data:1<br>
Array ( ) Base array: 1<br>
1 Dump array result: 1<br>
298 ID value from data:1<br>
Array ( ) Base array: 1<br>
1 Dump array result: 1<br>
301 ID value from data:1<br>
Array ( ) Base array: 1<br>
1 Dump array result: 1<br>
```

What I'm expecting to see is an array of the ID values from `$party->id`, so a `print_r` of `$p_id` should result something like `Array(295, 298, 301)`.

Instead the result is `1`. Not `array(1)`. Just `1`.

For even more clarity, the data this is pulling in doesn't even have `1` as an id. So it shouldn't even exist.

I've included the `print_r`, and `var_dump` results, so you can see the raw debug output.

Comment: please specify the expected output

Comment: What output are you aiming for? If you don't want decoration around the values then remove the var_dump() and print_r() bits so you just get the variable's value. If you want something else, show us your desired output?

Comment: party->id != 1 ?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Show us all code, it may be problem with $opp->participants

Comment: `array_push` is returning true (1) because it was successful. You don't need to set `$p_id` to `array_push`.

Comment: Change the line to just `array_push($p_id, "$party->id");`

Comment: Good call @Anthony I forgot about that detail. That solved it. Thanks. Put up your answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to assign the result of the array_push() to $p_id. As per PHP documentation the return value of an array_push() function is the new number of elements in the array and not the array itself. [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Change the code to :

```
array_push($p_id, "$party->id");
```

That should do it.